# How to anchor a dynamic div to the screen?

Tags: css, html, width, screen

I'm looking for a way to devide my screen perfectly into two divs.
One small fixed sized on the left and one with dynamic width on the right.

I didn't figured out how to do this yet. 
Because the width in percentage is not proportional.

For example:
http://jsfiddle.net/acmnU/2/

If you resize the result field or the overall width you see that the green
div will not resize in proportion with the screen.
If the field gets to small the green div slips under the red one.

what I need is some kind of anchor. So that the green div fill the entire screen without
getting to big.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="left">left</div>

        <div class="right">right</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
height: 300px;
}

#content {
    height: 100%;
}

.left {

    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}
.right {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I have interpreted your question correctly. You can [try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dB9x/)

```
body {
    height: 300px;
}

#content {
    height: 100%;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}
.right {
    margin-left: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I have set the `margin-left` of the `.right` to equal that of the width of `.left`. But don't `float` the right panel and it will fill the remaining space.

[image: Result]

Comment: thank you scott thats exactly what I was searching for. nice and simple.

Answer (score 0):

I advise using a layout framework to ease this type of think. Bootstrap is a good one but there are lots of others.

If you want to do it manually, you need to give the Content class a width, and use relative positioning.

Comment: Hey i do use Bootstrap but the container-fluid class didn't do the job as i want. I just started with bootstrap and have to figure out the most of its potential. Scoots approach work really well